# reassigning strings in a vector using loops

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I am a beginner learning c++ trying to write a program that will read words into a vector, replace "bad" words with "BLEEP" and print out the vector after it is censored. 
    Here is where I think my mistakes might be...
nested loop - if in a while
words.size - should it be words.length?

Any insight is appreciated

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    cout << "type in text";
    vector<string> words;
    string word = "";
    while (cin >> word)
    {
        {
            if (word == "boo" || "broccoli" || "moist")
                word = "BLEEP";
        }
        words.push_back(word);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
        cout << "" << words[i] << "";
}
```

Comment: `if (word == "boo" || word == "broccoli" || word == "moist")`

Comment: `if (word == "boo" || "broccoli" || "moist")`  When we speak English, this is how we word this.  When you speak `C++`, this isn't correct.

Comment: I believe I have corrected this, replacing it with:
if ((word == "boo") || (word=="broccoli") || (word=="moist"))
Still not getting the output I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (word == "boo" || "broccoli" || "moist")
```

is not the correct way to chain multiple conditions together.  You need to recheck the condition in each part.

```
if (word == "boo" || word == "broccoli" || word == "moist")
```

When you have

```
if (word == "boo" || "broccoli" || "moist")
```

It is translated to

```
if (word == "boo" || true || true)
```

So it will always be true.

Comment: I believe I have corrected this, replacing it with: 
if ((word == "boo") || (word=="broccoli") || (word=="moist")) Still not getting 
the output I'm looking for

Comment: @JacobEverettFarr It looks like you also need to change `cout << "" << words[i] << "";` to `cout << words[i] << " ";`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Nathan. I have made the correction. I am down to one error which is "<signed/unsigned mismatch".

Does this have to do with comparing int i to a string vector in my conditional?

Comment: @Jacob Yes.  To get rid of the warning change `int i = 0` to `std::size_t i = 0`

Comment: Nathan, again, thank you for the help. the program is error free but still not accomplishing the task I wish. When I read it, I see the following happening:
ask user to input text --> assign text to a vector and also check if words are "bad" --> reassign bad words to "bleep" --> print the vector. 


Instead, it is printing exactly what I have put in and not reassigning the "bad" words. Any thoughts?

Comment: that exact same code is printing the original input for me even for "bad" words.
Could this be the way I am terminating my input? I am typing in the words followed by "|". Should I be hitting return after this? 

Sorry to bother you with such entry level questions. 

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Jacob Are you running from the console?  If so you should just type in what you want to convert and then press enter.  So type `boo broccoli moist not a bad word` and then press enter

Comment: I have reset all my default settings to eliminate ide influence. 
I copy and paste the code and run it in a Visual C++ file. 
When the console appears, I type in "boo", hit enter and nothing appears. If I press up arrow, the word "boo" will appear. I am learning from Bjarnes Programming Principles textbook. The textbook instructs us to use visual studio 2005 and FLTK. I have Visual studio community 2015 but FLTK never installed successfully. I believe this to be an error of an outdated book but am unsure. WIll uninstall visual studio and reinstall.

Comment: @Jacob No need to uninstall visual studio and reinstall.  I forgot that you have to press ctrl+Z and then enter after you type in your text to send an end of stream to the program.  This has to do with the while loop as it will always wait for more input until you tell it to end.

Comment: Ahhh! Finally. I can not thank you enough, @NathanOliver